# How to find $f(x)$ given $f'(x)$

Tags: functions, derivatives, function-and-relation-composition

I am dealing with a problem where I have the derivative $f'(x)$ in function of its antiderivative $f(x)$. How can I solve this?

$f'(f(x))$ is linear (just assume any linear function, for sake of simplicity), but I almost surely know that $f(x)$ is a hyperbole.

@edit:
The problem is along the lines of: "A particle travels towards a point $r$ such that, in any instant, the remaining time until its arrival $q$ with its instant velocity $V(S)$ is the same. Find $S(t)$."

From there it was easy to deduce the following:

$$q = \frac{r - S}{V(S)}$$

$$V(S) = \frac{r - S}{q}$$

$$V(S(t)) = \frac{r - S(t)}{q}$$

I tried to solve it in a physics way, using classical dynamics, but the results were weird. Is there any other way to solve it?

Comment: Can you state the particular problem you're trying to solve explicitly, please? I'm getting a suspicion that you may be confusing $f'(x)$ with $f'(f(x))$, but it is hard to be sure without knowing what you're _really_ doing.

Comment: The problem is pretty physics oriented, but yes, I can. Let me edit the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're getting yourself led astray by bad notation -- especially, you're writing $V(S(t))$ where you should just be writing $V(t)$ or $\frac{d}{dt}S(t)$ or $S'(t)$. The problem text you're quoting seems to use the same wrong notation, so it's not purely your fault, but what you *should* be doing is
$$ q = \frac{r-S(t)}{S'(t)} $$
rearranging to
$$ S'(t) = \frac 1q(r-S(t)) $$

If we switch to a new variable $u(t)=r-S(t)$ we get
$$ u'(t) = \frac{-1}q u(t) $$
which you ought to recognize as the standard differential equation whose solution is
$$ u(t) =  C e^{-t/q} $$
where $C$ is a constant of integration, and therefore
$$ S(t) = r - C e^{-t/q} $$

In other words, the distance to point $r$ varies as an exponential decay with time constant $q$. (With a bit of experience you will be able to recognize that directly from the problem description, and not need to do the algebra explicitly).

Comment: Yes, the notation change helped to clear the concept on my mind. One more thing, I still haven't studied integration, so could you explain a little more on C?

Comment: @eduardogbg: "Constant of integration" in this context is just a conventional word for "a constant that you can adjust freely to make different solutions". In particular, if you know where your particle _starts out_ at $t=0$, you can make $S(0)$ have this value by choosing an appropriate value for $C$.

Comment: Like in the integral of a polynomial where we have the $+ C$ at the end? Got it

Comment: @eduardogbg: Yes. Meanwhile, _physically_ $C$ also has the job of making the $Ce^{-t/q}$ term have the dimension of length; the exponential in itself is always dimensionless, but if $C$ is a length, then the units will work out correctly.

Comment: Yes, of course, I almost forgot that the dimension we had was time on $t$, and as I may guess, $e^{1s}$ is dimensionless, right?

Comment: @eduardo: $e^{(\cdots)}$ always dimensionless, and the exponent must _also_ be dimensionless. So $e^{1\,\rm s}$ does not make sense -- luckily there's a $q$ there which is also a duration, so $t/q$ is in fact dimensionless.

Comment: Makes sense, I was getting confused, because no calculator could give me an answer to an exponent with dimension. Thank you very much for the detailed explanations. I'm satisfied now.